# Adding security to AWS cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, web, amazon-cloudfront

I have created a website where all the contents like videos, thumbnails etc are served from AWS CloudFront. I want that the link of cloudfront to be only accessible on my website, if someone have link of my cloudfront content, they cannot access or download the content

I've tried AWS web ACLs but it doesnt work for me
So any solutions?

Comment: It's not possible without proper authorisation and authentication system.

Answer (score 0):

This use case can be easily implemented with help of AWS Lambda Edge functions (VIewer request). You can check the below blog for the same. Instead of using SSH key for authentication what you could do is, whenever your website makes request to AWS Cloudfront you could ask your website to inject a custom header. At Lambda edge you could authorize the request on basis of that header and it's value & if header is not found you could send Unauthorized message to request initiator. You can also find the lambda edge code snippet in the blog itself.

Blog Link : [go to blog](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/authentication-custom-usecase-different-approch-ayush-ganatra/?trackingId=7WDv%2FpQqTr25lR1VcgA2%2BA%3D%3D)